# SyncAdapter only on WIFI

Tags: android, synchronization

I want to run my `SyncAdapter` only on Wifi. In the beginning of `onPerformSync`, I can check if wifi is present. If it's not, I want to postpone it until there is WIFI available.

I know of `syncresult.delayUntil` but that means that the sync adapter is uselessly called every x minutes although the wifi could be disabled for example for the entire day. Also, from what I've read `delayUntil` does not apply if you use `triggerSync` directly.

What is the best approach here? Apps like Evernote seem to have this option of syncing only on WIFI.

Answer (score 2):

Don't set your `SyncAdapter` to run periodically.

Instead add a `BroadcastReceiver` to your app with this filter:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

and in the `BroadcastReceiver` code, check if WiFi was turned on, and if so, call:

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(<Your account, <Your authority>, extras);
```

To request Android to run your `SyncAdapter`.

Comment: If this approach is used by all apps it will hurt user's network experience.